# TSQLQuery, TFields and operator []

Tags: c++, c++builder, vcl, dbexpress

I have a query, using TSQLQuery that goes like this

```
TSQLQuery* tq = new TSQLQuery(NULL);
tq->SQLConnection = atdbDM->SQLConnection1;
tq->SQL->Add("SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID();");
tq->Open();
int insert_id = tq->Fields->operator [](0)->AsInteger;
```

The expression

```
int insert_id = tq->Fields->operator [](0)->AsInteger;
```

is pretty clunky. Looking at the implementation, the operator[] is overloaded in the header:

```
public:
    TField* operator[](int Index) { return Fields[Index]; }
```

However, if I call:

```
int insert_id = tq->Fields[0]->AsInteger;
```

I get the compiler error:

```
[bcc32 Error] TRegisterFreshCSBatchForm.cpp(97): E2288 Pointer to structure 
required on left side of -> or ->*
TRegisterFreshCSBatchForm::mRegisterBtnClick(TObject *)
```

Any ideas why the above call don't compile?? I must be missing something..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct syntax is

```
int insert_id = (*tq->Fields)[0]->AsInteger;
```

There must be a class object, not a pointer, involved for an overloaded operator to kick in.

Comment: The alternative is to simply not use `TFields::operator[]` at all, use the `TFields::Fields[]` property directly instead: `int insert_id = tq->Fields->Fields[0]->AsInteger;` The `TFields::operator[]` doesn't really gain you anything except an extra `CALL` instruction. The only reason it exists in C++ at all is to provide a C++ syntax that is closer to Delphi syntax when accessing `default` properties.